# How to Implement AsyncTask to delay on button

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

*How to merge following code with Async Task  . I see lots of tutorials and make changes in code but unable to do completely. This code is completely fine and working proper but some one advise me to make it Async Task so that when i press button it will take some time to start. so please someone add async task code in it so that its work proper.*

**Code:-**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;
private CountDownTimer counterTimer;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.question);
            processScreen();
     }
            /**
     * Configure current game and get question
     */
     private void processScreen()
     {
    currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
    Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
    nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    /**
     * Update the question and answer options..
     */
    setQuestions();

}


/**
 * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
 * current question
 */
private void setQuestions() {
    //set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

    TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

    int score = currentGame.getScore();
    String scr = String.valueOf(score);
    TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score1.setText(scr);

    counterTimer=new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {                
            if(currentGame.getRound()==20)
                System.exit(0);
            currentGame.decrementScore();
            processScreen();
                         }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
            time.setText( ""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                            }
    };
    counterTimer.start();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
    if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
    {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Are you sure?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Yes",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
     int id) {
            finish();
             }
         }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

            }

    else
    {
        if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

    /**
     * check if end of game
     */
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
        //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
        else
        {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
    }
    }
  }



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


/**
 * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
 * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
 */
private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

    Button b=(Button) v;
    String answer = b.getText().toString();
     counterTimer.cancel();
     b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);
     b.setEnabled(false);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
            //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementScore();
        }
        else{
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
            //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.decrementScore1();
        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

Hope Anyone Can Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which code do you want to have delayed?

Comment: i wanted to delay on button(nextBtn1,nextBtn2,nextBtn3,nextBtn4).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Runnable` :

```
private static final int START_AFTER_SECONDS = 10; 
...
Runnable mRunnable;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //DELAYED CODE HERE
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, START_AFTER_SECONDS * 1000);
```

Comment: It is not clear for me what code You want to delay. Just put it in place where this code is and paste this code inside `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is not the right tool for this job.  Try this

```
getHandler().postDelayed(
     new Runnable { 
           void run() 
           { 
             methodToCall();
           } 
        }, delayTimeInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Can u merge this code with my code ,i already tried but not successful to implement it.

Comment: I am really stuck with  runnable, Handler and asyncTask.